How to solve this (0 , _index.requireNativeComponent) is not a function in react native
When facing the (0 , _index.requireNativeComponent) is not a function error in React Native, particularly when dealing with bottom tabs and running on web view, it's often related to the setup of the project or the compatibility of the libraries with the web environment.
